# Prove $ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln ^3 x}{(1+x)^{n}} d x =A+B \pi^2$ for some rational numbers $A$ and $B$, where $n\neq 1 $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, pi

After knowing that $$
I_2=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\ln ^3 x}{(1+x)^{2}} d x \stackrel{x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}}{=} -\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\ln ^3 x}{(1+x)^{2}} d x \Rightarrow \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\ln ^3 x}{(1+x)^{2}} d x=0
$$
I start to investigate the integrals with higher powers
$$I_n=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\ln ^3 x}{(1+x)^{n}} d x  $$
where $n$ is a natural number greater than $2$.

We first split the interval into two as
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\ln ^3 x}{(1+x)^3} d x & =\int_0^1 \frac{\ln ^3 x}{(1+x)^3} d x+\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{\ln ^3 x}{(1+x)^3} d x \\
& =\int_0^1 \frac{\ln ^3 x}{(1+x)^3} d x+\int_1^0 \frac{\ln ^3\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^3} \frac{d x}{-x^2} \\
& =\int_0^1 \frac{\ln ^3 x}{(1+x)^3} d x-\int_0^1 \frac{x \ln ^3 x}{(1+x)^3} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
For any $|x|<1$, we have $$
\frac{1}{1+x}=\sum_{k \rightarrow 0}^{\infty}(-1)^k x^k
$$
Differentiating both sides w.r.t. $x$ twice yields
$$
\frac{1}{(1+x)^3}=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k(k+2)(k+1) x^k
$$

Plugging into the integrand, we have $$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln ^3 x}{(1+x)^3}dx=\frac{1}{2}\left[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k(k+2)(k+1)\left( \int_0^1 x^k \ln ^3 x d x-\int_0^1 x^{k+1} \ln ^3 x d x \right)\right] 
$$
Noting that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 x^n \ln ^3 x d x & =\left.\frac{\partial^3}{\partial a^3} \int_0^1 x^a d x\right|_{x=w} \\
& =\left.\frac{\partial^3}{\partial a^3}\left(\frac{1}{a+1}\right)\right|_{x=n} \\
& =-\frac{6}{(n+1)^4}
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}I_3&=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k(k+2)(k+1)\left[-\frac{6}{(k+1)^4}+\frac{6}{(k+2)^4}\right]\\&= 3 \left[-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k(k+2)}{(k+1)^3}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k(k+1)}{(k+2)^3}\right]\\&= -3\left[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k(k+2)}{(k+1)^3}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^kk}{(k+1)^3}\right]\\&=-3 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k(2 k+2)}{(k+1)^3}\\&=-6 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^2}\\&=-\frac{\pi^2}{2}\end{aligned}
$$

Let’s continue with $I_4$ by considering their difference
$$
\begin{aligned}
D & =\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\ln ^3 x}{(1+x)^3} d x -\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\ln ^3 x}{(1+x)^4} d x \\
& =\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x \ln ^3 x}{(1+x)^4} d x \\
& =\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{x} \ln ^3 \frac{1}{x}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^4} \frac{d x}{x^2} \\
& =-\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x \ln ^3 x}{(1+x)^4} d x \\
& =-D\\\Rightarrow D&=0 
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence $$\boxed{I_4=I_3=-\frac{\pi^2}{2} }$$

By Wolfram-alpha, we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
& I_5=-\frac{1}{24}\left(6+11 \pi^2\right) \\
& I_6=-\frac{1}{12}\left(6+5 \pi^2\right) \\
& I_7=-\frac{1}{360}(255+137 \pi^2)
\end{aligned}
$$

I guess that in general, $$
I_n=A+B \pi^2 \textrm{  for some rational numbers } A \textrm{ and }B.
$$

Can we prove it further?  Your help or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: First, I think you meant $A, B$ are some rational numbers, right? Otherwise it will be a meaningless statement since you can take $A = I_n, B = 0$. Also, in your question, $I_7$ is not the form you stated.

Comment: Little typo : a square is lacking in the expression of $I_7$...

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  Fixed.

Comment: To compute $I_n$ consider $\text{B}(s,n+1-s)$ for $s>0$ and derive three times wrt s and then $s\rightarrow 0$. $B$ is the Euler's Beta function.

Comment: @FDP's method eventually writes $I_n$ as $A+6B\zeta(2)$ with $A,\,B$ rationals expressible in terms of generalized harmonic numbers indexed at $n-2$. The appearances of $\zeta(2)$ is due to the value of $\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\ln\Gamma(z)$ at $z=1$.

Comment: It seems that\begin{align}\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\ln ^2 x}{(1+x)^{n}} d x=A+B\pi^2,\text{for} A,B \in \mathbb{Q},n\geq 2,\text{integer}\end{align}

Comment: I agree with you. In general, I guess that $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln ^m x}{(1+x)^n} d x=\sum_{k=0}^{\left[\frac{m}{2}\right]} a_k \pi^{2 k}$ where $a_k\in Q$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**By differentiation**

We may start our journey with the integral
$$
I(a)=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\ln ^3 x}{(a+x)^2} d x
$$
Using substitution $ax\mapsto x$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I(a) & =\frac{1}{a} \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\ln ^3(a x)}{(1+x)^2} d x \\
& =\frac{1}{a} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln ^3 a+3 \ln ^2 a\ln x+3 \ln a \ln ^2 x+\ln ^3 x}{(1+x)^2} dx
\end{aligned}
$$
Noting that $\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\ln ^{2n+1} x}{(1+x)^2} d x=0$, we have $$
I(a)=\frac{\ln ^3 a}{a} \underbrace{ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\left(1+x\right)^2}d x}_{=1} +  \frac{3 \ln a}{a} \underbrace{
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln ^2 x}{(1+x)^2} d x}_{\frac{\pi^2}{3}  } =\frac{\ln ^3 a}{a}+\frac{\pi^2 \ln a}{a} $$
By differentiating $I(a)$ w.r.t. $a$ by $n-2$ times, we get

$$\boxed{I_n=\left.\frac{(-1)^n}{(n-1) !} \frac{\partial^{n-2}}{\partial a^{n-2}} \left(\frac{\ln ^3 a}{a}+\frac{\pi^2 \ln a}{a} \right)\right|_{a=1}=A_n+B_n\pi^2 } $$
where $ \left. \displaystyle  A_n= \frac{(-1)^n}{4(n-1) !} \frac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial a^{n-1}} \left(\ln ^4 a\right) \right|_{a=1} $ and $\displaystyle  \left.  B_n= \frac{(-1)^n}{2(n-1) !} \frac{\partial^{n-1}}{\partial a^{n-1}} \left(\ln^2 a\right) \right|_{a=1} $ are **rational.**

For examples,
$$
\left. I_5=-\frac{1}{24} \frac{\partial^4}{\partial a^4}\left(\frac{\ln ^4 a}{4}+\frac{ \pi^2 \ln^2 a}{2} \right)\right|_{a=1} =-\frac{1}{24}\left(6+11 \pi^2\right)
$$
$$I_6=\left.\frac{1}{120} \frac{\partial^5}{\partial a^5}\left(\frac{\ln ^4 a}{4}+\frac{\pi^2 \ln^2 a}{2}\right)\right|_{a=1}= -\frac{1}{12}\left(6+5 \pi^2\right)$$

Comment: So interesting, though I don’t know about it. Can you give me some hints?

Comment: I can post the proof as an answer if you are interested. Not so difficult to show it though.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I urge to learn.

Comment: I posted a proof (with slight corrections).

Answer (score 6):

**By Mathematical Induction**

I am going to prove, by Mathematical Inductio,that
$$P(n):I_n= \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\ln ^3 x}{(1+x)^n} d x=A_n+B_n\pi^2,$$
where $n\ge 2 , A_n$ and $B_n$ are **rational**.

First of all, we have
$$I_2=0, I_4=I_3=-\frac{\pi^2}{2} \tag*{} $$
Therefore $P(2), P(3)$ and $P(4)$ are true.

Now assume that $P(n)$ are true for all $2\le n \le k-1$.

When $n=k$, letting $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}  $ yields $$
\begin{aligned}
I_{k}&=-\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^{k-2} \ln ^3 x}{(1+x)^{k}} d x\\&=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{(1+x-1)^{k-2}\ln^3x}{(1+x)^{k}}dx\\
& =-\sum_{j=0}^{k-2}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k-2 \\
j
\end{array}\right)(-1)^{k-2-j}\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\ln ^3 x}{(1+x)^{k-j} }d x\\& =-I_{k}+\sum_{j=1}^{k-2}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k-2 \\
j
\end{array}\right)(-1)^{k-1-j} I_{k-j}\\&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^{k-2}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k-2\\
j
\end{array}\right)(-1)^{k-1-j} I_{k-j}\\&=  \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^{k-2}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k-2\\
j
\end{array}\right)(-1)^{k-1-j} (A_{k-j}+B_{k-j} \pi^2) \quad \textrm{ (By Ind. Hypo.)} \\&= A_{k}+B_{k} \pi^2,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $ \displaystyle  A_k= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^{k-2}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k-2\\
j
\end{array}\right)(-1)^{k-1-j} A_{k-j} $ and $ \displaystyle  B_k=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{j=1}^{k-2}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k-2\\
j
\end{array}\right)(-1)^{k-1-j} B_{k-j}$ are **rational** too and hence $P(k)$ is also true.

By the principle of Mathematical Induction, we can conclude that for all natural numbers $n$, $$ \boxed{ I_n=A_n+B_n \pi^2} \tag*{} $$

Comment: The proof is questionable, given that in the 3rd equality $$\frac{(1+x-1)^{k-2}}{(1+x)^{k}}
\ne -\sum_{j=0}^{k-2}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k-2 \\
j
\end{array}\right)\frac{(-1)^j}{(1+x)^{k-j} }
$$

Comment: Is $(1+x-1)^{k-2}=\sum_{j=0}^{k-2}(-1)^j\left(\begin{array}{c}k-2 \\ j\end{array}\right)(1+x)^j$ right?

Comment: It should be $${(1+x-1)^{k-2}}
=\sum_{j=0}^{k-2}\left(\begin{array}{c}
k-2 \\
j
\end{array}\right)(-1)^{k-2-j}(1+x)^{j}
$$

Comment: Oh, you are right. I’m too careless.

Comment: The rest of the proof is no longer valid since $I_k$ cancels out from both sides

Answer (score 3):

Using the results in one of the answers, the coefficients $A_n$ and $B_n$ may be expressed in terms of the [Nörlund polynomials](http://dlmf.nist.gov/24.16.i). Indeed
\begin{align*}
A_n  & = \frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{(n - 1)!}}\left[ {\frac{{{\rm d}^{n - 2} }}{{{\rm d}z^{n - 2} }}\frac{{\log ^3 z}}{z}} \right]_{z = 1}  = \frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{n - 1}}\frac{1}{{2\pi {\rm i}}}\oint_{(1 + )} {\frac{{\log ^3 z}}{z}\frac{{{\rm d}z}}{{(z - 1)^{n - 1} }}} 
\\ & = \frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{n - 1}}\frac{1}{{2\pi {\rm i}}}\oint_{(0 + )} {\frac{{t^3 }}{{({\rm e}^t  - 1)^{n - 1} }}{\rm d}t}  = \frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{n - 1}}\frac{1}{{2\pi {\rm i}}}\oint_{(0 + )} {\left( {\frac{t}{{{\rm e}^t  - 1}}} \right)^{n - 1} \frac{{{\rm d}t}}{{t^{n - 4} }}} 
\\ & = \frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{n - 1}}\frac{{B_{n - 5}^{(n - 1)} }}{{(n - 5)!}},
\end{align*}
provided $n\ge 5$. In a similar manner
$$
B_n  = \frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{n - 1}}\frac{{B_{n - 3}^{(n - 1)} }}{{(n - 3)!}},
$$
provided $n\ge 3$. Also $A_2=A_3=A_4=0$ and $B_2=0$. To leading order
$$
A_n  \sim  - \frac{{\log ^3 n}}{n},\quad B_n  \sim  - \frac{{\log n}}{n}
$$
as $n\to+\infty$ (cf. Section $3.3$ in [this paper](https://ir.cwi.nl/pub/2223)).

Comment: Thank you very much for your proof. I’ll learn it later.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln ^3 x}{(1+x)^n} d x\\
=&\ \frac{d^3}{da^3} \bigg(\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^a}{(1+x)^n} d x\bigg)_{a=0}=
 \frac{d^3}{da^3}\bigg( \frac{\pi a\csc\pi a}{(n-1)!} \prod_{k=1}^{n-2}(k-a)\bigg)_{a=0}\\
=& \ \frac1{n-1}\bigg( 3a_1a_2-a_1^3-2a_3 -a_1\pi^2 \bigg)
=A+B\pi^2
\end{align}
where $a_i=\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\frac1{k^i}$. Explicitly
\begin{align}
&A=-\frac1{n-1}\left(\bigg( \sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\frac1{k}\bigg)^3+2 \sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\frac1{k^3} -3\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\frac1{k} \cdot\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\frac1{k^2}
\right)\\
&B= -\frac1{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\frac1{k}
\end{align}

Comment: Was about to answer with this same technique. Much simpler!